# Ruby check if nil and set different value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I check if the something is nil and if its nil then use a different function to set value.

`Integer($evm.root.attributes["dialog_cloud_network"])` can be nil in some cases and so I want to use a different function `query_catalogitem(:cloud_network)` to set value.

Example:

```
cloud_network_id =  Integer($evm.root.attributes["dialog_cloud_network"]) || query_catalogitem(:cloud_network).
```

The above doesn't work because `cloud_network_id` ends with value nil instead of getting the value from `query_catalogitem(:cloud_network)`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: are you sure that `query_catalogitem(:cloud_network)` is not evaluting to `nil` too?

Comment: if `cloud_network_id` is nil, then both functions are returning `nil`. Verify whether `query_catalogitem(:cloud_network)` is returning a value or not.

Comment: _"`Integer(...)` can be nil in some cases"_ – no, the [`Integer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#Integer-method) method call with one argument either returns an integer or raises an exception. It cannot return `nil` when called that way.

Comment: No `query_catalogitem(:cloud_network) ` is returning `1` if I remove the `Integer($evm.root.attributes["dialog_cloud_network"])`

Comment: @Robert something else must be going on because a) `nil || value` will always return `value` and b) the left-hand value in your example cannot be `nil` in the first place. (because `Integer()` doesn't work that way)

Comment: `  $evm.root.attributes["dialog_cloud_network"].to_i || query_catalogitem(:cloud_network)` If I try that then it returns zero. How can I put a condition to use the second function?

Comment: @Stefan yea Nil is returned by something else. But I"m trying to say that my second condition isn't working at all. I need a way to try second condition if first condition is zero or empty or nil.

Comment: _"Nil is returned by something else"_ – can you post the actual code then? _"zero or empty or nil"_ – be more specific, please. What kind of object(s) are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
cloud_network_id = $evm.root.attributes["dialog_cloud_network"]&.to_i || 
                   query_catalogitem(:cloud_network)
```

Comment: @mechnicov I used the safe navigation operator (`&.`) in my answer and `nil&.to_i` will return `nil`.

Comment: `$evm.root.attributes["dialog_cloud_network"].to_i || 
                   query_catalogitem(:cloud_network)
` Returns zero instead of nil and the `query_catalogitem(:cloud_network)` doesn't run at all. I'm not sure if `&` would make a difference?

Comment: @Robert it makes [difference](https://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) but be careful if it is some other object. If so, it's better to use `try`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `exception: false` to [`Integer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer)

In this case `Integer` may be `nil` (if impossible to convert `$evm.root.attributes["dialog_cloud_network"]` to Integer)

Also is better to specify base (10)

```rb
cloud_network_id =
  Integer($evm.root.attributes["dialog_cloud_network"], 10, exception: false) ||
    query_catalogitem(:cloud_network)
```